# how to flatten the second element of the input tuple in a process in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

```
...
filter (ch_splitfq)
.set {ch_fq}    // tuple: val(id), path(sample.clean_*.fq.gz)

fqcheck (ch_fq.flatten()???)
.collect()
.set {ch_fqcheck}
```

ch_fq is like: sample1, [sample1.clean_1.fq.gz, sample1.clean_2.fq.gz]
I want to split ch_fq into two channels and give each to fqcheck process. I thought of flatten(), but only flatten the second element and keep the id. the two channels given to fqcheck process should be like: tuple val(sample1), path(clean_1.fq.gz) and tuple val(sample1), path(clean_2.fq.gz), respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you necessarily need two channels here. I think what you want is just one channel that produces the transposition. For this, you can use the [`transpose`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#transpose) operator:

```
fqcheck( ch_fq.transpose() )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So whats the opposite of transpose? Say I want to collect multiple outputs (tuple val(id), path(fq1) and tuple val(id), path(fq2)) to tuple val(id), path(fq1 and fq2) ?

Comment: @CaiBian The opposite I think is the [`groupTuple`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) operator. You would need to use `size: 2` and check to see if you get the desired sort order, where fq1 is first and fq2 is second. It may be simpler and more robust to import `fqcheck` using a [module alias](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-aliases) and use something like: `fqcheck_1( ch_fq.map { id, reads -> tuple(id, reads[0]) } )` and `fqcheck_2( ch_fq.map { id, reads -> tuple(id, reads[1]) } )` instead.

Comment: @CaiBian This would then let you [`join`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) the outputs: `fqcheck_1.join( fqcheck_2 ).map { id, fq1, fq2 -> tuple( id, [fq1, fq2] ) }`